# Alternate option in css when something is not supported

Tags: html, css

I have built a website that uses vh for measurement, but came accross the problem that some browsers are not supporting vh, how can i write my css that tries vh but if it does not work it changes to another form of measurement?
Thanks

Here is an example of a css that I would need to change

```
img{
 max-height: 90vh;
  cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Put the fallback rule before the current one using `vh`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure but you could try to set max-height two times. One with percentage measurement and the latter one with `vh`. The browser should ignore the unknown one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS requires that browsers ignore rules that are not recognised.

```
max-height: 100px;
max-height: 90vh;
```

If the browser supports `vh` then the second rule will be recognised and the first rule will overridden by it.

If it does not, then the second rule will be ignored and the first rule will apply.